# How to run Snakemake >= 8 on a Slurm cluster?

Tags: snakemake

I need to code a workflow and I've been looking for workflow management systems. I chose Snakemake because of its Conda integration and because I want a workflow that you can easily run locally or in a cluster (Linux). So, after reading documentation and tutorials, I made this Conda environment in the login machine of my cluster:

```yaml
name: testing
channels:
    - conda-forge
    - bioconda
    - defaults
    - R
dependencies:
    - r-base=4.3.2
    - snakemake=8.4.2
```

Then I made a testing rule and then I went `snakemake --cores 1`, everything worked fine. Now I want to test whether Snakemake sends the rules to Slurm. So I tried the `--cluster` command that I've seen in the documentation and in nearly every tutorial:

```
snakemake: error: unrecognized arguments: --cluster
```

I also tried `--slurm`, not recognized either. `--cluster-config` also doesn't appear to be understood by Snakemake.

Looking for some explanation I found that apparently Snakemake 8 included not backwards compatible changes (https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/migration.html). It looks like now things are like this:

```
New designed: Now if you want to use --cluster CMD, please use --executor cluster-generic --cluster-generic-submit-cmd CMD instead.

Note you should install cluster-generic using command pip install snakemake-executor-cluster-generic
```

Well, ignoring the fact that neither pip or pip3, inside or outside Conda, finds such package (I suppose that this should be another question in its own), I am really, really confused because:

1. Snakemake latest documentation (8.4.3) still includes `--cluster` references that don't work anymore
2. Every time I search for tutorials/documentation outside of the official one, I find that they always use `--cluster`
3. Maybe I don't know how to properly look for information, but it seems like nobody is actually having issues with all of this migration stuff? It feels like I'm crazy, looking for something that doesn't really exist
4. This new way of managing cluster stuff looks somehow more complicated than the `--cluster` thing? I mean now I need to manually install something that before worked by default, and I can not even include that on the Conda environment YAML.

I'm a newbie in Snakemake and it looks that I just landed in a minefield full of breaking changes. **Should I send it all to hell and go for a Snakemake 7 version? Or should I keep going with version 8 so I get used to it because now this is how things work? In that case, do you know any resources where I can find how to run this thing?** I thought that choosing Snakemake would have the advantage of having a huge amount of useful documentation but honestly I'm going crazy.

Comment: There definitely is some growing pains in migrating to Snakemake>8. For docs on how to use SLURM on Snakemake 8 you can look here: https://snakemake.github.io/snakemake-plugin-catalog/plugins/executor/slurm.html

Personally, I am still actively using Snakemake 7.32.4 and find it easy to run on a SLURM cluster using the `--slurm` CLI option. 


To answer your fourth question, I believe some of the rationale for plugins was to create and use a generic plugin interface so that more executor/storage plugins could be easily developed and maintained separately from the main Snakemake codebase.

Comment: I had the same problem, but instead of snakemake-executor-cluster-generic,  I installed snakemake-executor-plugin-cluster-generic and used the command snakemake -j 6 --latency-wait 120 --executor cluster-generic --cluster-generic-submit-cmd "sbatch" and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into a very similar issue. I used to do something like this for a SGE/UGE cluster:

```bash
snakemake \
        --cluster-config cluster.json \
        -j 1 \
        --cluster 'qsub -q all.q -l h_vmem={cluster.mem} -pe smp {cluster.num_cores} -V -cwd'
```

Where the contents of `cluster.json` were:

```json
{
  "__default__": {
    "mem": "8G",
    "num_cores": "{threads}",
    "jobname": "{rule}"
  }
}
```

In Snakemake 8, it appears you first need to install a new plugin by going:

```bash
pip install snakemake-executor-plugin-cluster-generic
```

The `--cluster-config` argument is no longer available. So the first command becomes:

```bash
 snakemake \
         --executor cluster-generic \
         --cluster-generic-submit-cmd 'qsub -N {rule} -q all.q -l h_vmem=8G -pe smp {threads} -V -cwd'
```

This logic should work for other clusters (e.g. SLURM).